# How to access the new DLC levels?

Tags: crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy

Two new levels, [Future Tense](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP0002-CUSA07402_00-CRASHNSANELEVEL2) (brand new) and [Stormy Ascent](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP0002-CUSA07402_00-CRASHNSANELEVEL1) (reworked cut content from the original Crash Bandicoot) have been added to Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy. I don't necessarily want to play the remaster to completion because of [the less accurate character hitbox](https://www.reddit.com/r/crashbandicoot/comments/6ktajs/collision_detection_seems_off_can_anyone_compare/) and [shorter jump duration](https://twitter.com/DingDongVG/status/881967130110943239/video/1) can turn already quite difficult games to downright punishing.

Can the new levels be entered instantly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access Story Accent in *Crash Bandicoot*: You stand on the purple dot and press "select" to start the level, as with any other level. You can do this at any point in the game.

[image: Crash Bandicoot level selection menu]

To access Future Tense in *Crash Bandicoot 3*: move to the lit platform between the bridges

[image: Crash Bandicoot 3: Warped level selection menu]